# Register and login with google

Tags: laravel, google-signin

I have created a Laravel application in which I have implemented Login and register with Facebook and Google using the socialite package and it's been working as expected, however when a user doesn't login with google for a long time the next time they try to login they get the error

> Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?prettyPrint=false`
> resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: { "error":
> "invalid_request", "error_description": "Invalid Credentials" }

why is this the case?

Comment: Can you show us the code how you login and how you use Oauth2 ?

Comment: Most likely because the browser sends the token which is expired